# Customizing Donut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, donut-chart, react-google-charts

I am trying to build a donut chart

I want a design similar  the following image where the values are shown in between the coloured pie

```js
import DonutChart from 'react-d3-donut';

    let data = [{
      count: 20    ,  
      color: "red"  ,
      name: 'My name' 
      },{
        count:30,
        color:"green",
        name:"yeys"
      },{
        count:20,
        color:"orange",
        name:"yeys"
      }]
      <DonutChart
innerRadius={90}
outerRadius={100}
transition={true}
svgClass="example1"
pieClass="pie1"
displayTooltip={true}
strokeWidth={3}
data={data} />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: are there any other libraries that helps me in building this design]

Comment: Your snippet does not work

Comment: The component does not support labels on arcs: https://aviskarkc10.github.io/react-d3-donut/

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky is there any way that i can build this with D3 charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple donut chart with D3:

```js
const data = [
    {value: 20, text: 'First', color: 'red'},
    {value: 30, text: 'Second', color: 'green'},
    {value: 60, text: 'Third', color: 'blue'},
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));

const margin = 10;
const arcWidth = 30;
const radius = Math.min(width/2 - margin, height/2 - margin) - arcWidth / 2;
const center = {x: width / 2, y: height / 2};

let anglePos = 0;
const angleOffset = 0.025;

const sum = data.reduce((s, {value}) => s + value, 0);
data.forEach(({value, text, color}, index) => {
  const angle = Math.PI * 2 * value / sum;
  const start = {
    x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(anglePos + angleOffset),
    y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(anglePos + angleOffset),
  };
  anglePos += angle;
  const end = {
    x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(anglePos - angleOffset),
    y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(anglePos -angleOffset),
  };
  const flags = value / sum >= 0.5 ? '1 1 1' : '0 0 1';
  const pathId = `my-pie-chart-path-${index}`;
  svg.append('path')
    .attr('id', pathId)
    .attr('d', `M ${start.x},${start.y} A ${radius},${radius} ${flags} ${end.x},${end.y}`)
    .style('stroke', color)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke-width', arcWidth);
    
   svg.append('text')
    .attr('dy', 6)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .append('textPath')
    .attr('startOffset', angle * radius / 2)
    .attr('href', `#${pathId}`)
    .text(text)
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

An example with text backgrounds:

```js
const data = [
    {value: 20, text: 'First', color: 'red'},
    {value: 30, text: 'Second', color: 'green'},
    {value: 60, text: 'Third', color: 'blue'},
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));

const margin = 10;
const arcWidth = 30;
const radius = Math.min(width/2 - margin, height/2 - margin) - arcWidth / 2;
const center = {x: width / 2, y: height / 2};

let anglePos = 0;
const angleOffset = 0.025;

const sum = data.reduce((s, {value}) => s + value, 0);
data.forEach(({value, text, color}, index) => {
    const angle = Math.PI * 2 * value / sum;
  const start = {
    x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(anglePos + angleOffset),
    y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(anglePos + angleOffset),
  };
  anglePos += angle;
  const end = {
    x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(anglePos - angleOffset),
    y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(anglePos -angleOffset),
  };
  const flags = value / sum >= 0.5 ? '1 1 1' : '0 0 1';
  const pathId = `my-pie-chart-path-${index}`;
  svg.append('path')
    .attr('id', pathId)
    .attr('d', `M ${start.x},${start.y} A ${radius},${radius} ${flags} ${end.x},${end.y}`)
    //.attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .style('stroke', color)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke-width', arcWidth);
    
  const textBg = svg.append('path');
     
    const textElement = svg.append('text')
    .text(text)
    .attr('dy', 6)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
    
  const textBox = textElement.node().getBBox();
  textElement.text(null);
  const bgAngle = Math.abs(textBox.x) / radius;
  const midAngle = anglePos - angle / 2;
  const endBgAngle = midAngle + bgAngle;
  const startBg = {
    x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(midAngle - bgAngle),
    y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(midAngle - bgAngle),
  };
  const endBg = {
    x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(midAngle + bgAngle),
    y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(midAngle + bgAngle),
  };
textBg.attr('d', `M ${startBg.x},${startBg.y} A ${radius},${radius} 0 0 1 ${endBg.x},${endBg.y}`)
    .style('stroke', 'white')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .style('stroke-width', arcWidth * 0.6);
  
  textElement.append('textPath')
    .text(text)
    .attr('startOffset', angle * radius / 2)
    .attr('href', `#${pathId}`)
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Hi, can i add a bg color to the text first,second and third

Comment: Yes, see the second snippet

Comment: Hi, second css snippet doesnt change anything.

Comment: How do i get the centroid of each arc, like you have start point and end point right

Comment: You mean the coordinates of the center point of an arc?

Comment: Yes, i am tring to append a circle,  and fill text inside it, if i use start params it shows circles at the start of each arc    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", (start.x))
        .attr("cy", (start.y))
        .attr("r", 20);

Comment: `const arcCenter = { x: center.x + radius * Math.sin(anglePos + angle/2), y: center.y + radius * -Math.cos(anglePos + angle/2) };` if you calculate the center point right after `const start =  ...`, and before `anglePos += angle;`

Comment: Hey man, it worked perfectly,can i fill in text inside the circle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231742/discussion-between-tej-and-michael-rovinsky).

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I will appreciate very much if you mark my answer as correct and upvote it