# I am trying to build a d3 donut chart, i want to split each arc and show value in between the arcs and also i am trying to add img inside donut

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, donut-chart

[image]

```html
import * as d3 from "d3";

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    var dataset = [{
      color: "red",
      value: 20,image:'https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/waves-water-river-sea-meet-each-1529923664'
    }, {
      color: "violet",
      value: 30
    }, {
      color: "orange",
      value: 40
    }, {
      color: "green",
      value: 10
    }];
    
    var width = 460,
      height = 300,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    
    // var color = d3.category20();
    
    var pie = d3.pie().padAngle(0.1)
      .sort(null).value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });;
    
    var arc1 = d3.arc()
    /*   .innerRadius(radius - 18)
      .outerRadius(radius - 13);
       */
    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 20)
      .outerRadius(radius - 10);
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
    
    var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
      .data(pie([{
        color: "white",
        value: 1
      }]))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return d.data.color;
      })
      .attr("d", arc1);
    
    var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", "10")
      .attr("stroke","none")
      .attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
        return d.data.color;
      })
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", arc);
      
    /* svg.append("text")
      .text("20/12")
      .attr("class", "units-label") */
      
    // var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data([0].image);
    //             imgs.enter()
    //             .append("svg:image")
    
  
 
return <div className="body"></div>

  }
}

export default App;
```

with the attached code , i am able to get the donut chart, how do i split each arc and show value in there, and i am trying to add an image inside the donut chart, i tried multiple methods to append an image tag to attribute but it doesnt work, how to overcome this issue, i tried adding a text which works perfectly fine inside the donut

Comment: Your snippet does not work. Also, I'm quite sure I answered a similar question of yours already...

Comment: This is from D3 chart, can you try copying the snippet to codesandbox,

Comment: Did you check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282441/customizing-donut-chart/67297778#67297778 ?

Comment: Hi, it doesnt fit my requirement, i want a space in the middle of each arc where i can show count

Comment: @Tej add your current working code  - use the code snippet, jsfiddle or other tool for create a [mcve].